# Table gigpost_category has no column named titled

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a simple blog and I'm facing this problem. When I try to add a model in my admin panel it shows me this error.

Here is the code :

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    titled=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Gigpost(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,blank=False)
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
    categories=models.OneToOneField(Category,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default='',blank=False)
    published_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.TextField(default='',max_length=None,blank=False)
    mainphoto=models.ImageField(default='')
    photo=models.ImageField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment_area(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
    comment=models.TextField(max_length=None,default='')
    commented_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Gigpost , Category

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Gigpost)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

The error message :

```
OperationalError at /admin/gigpost/category/add/
table gigpost_category has no column named titled
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/gigpost/category/add/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
table gigpost_category has no column named titled
```

Comment: Have you recently added the title field? Did you create the new migration and run it?

Comment: i added the title when i created the model , i just renamed category's title by changing it 'titled' , and i run migration

Comment: did you do `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: Your code has several errors. Why are you creating an abstract model if you are not inheriting from it? How should it return self.title if there is only a field called titled?
Run makemigrations and migrate to migrate changes on your models to the db.

Comment: @errorinpersona  i did the changes and run the migrations but still the same error

Comment: @gdef_ yes i did

Comment: If you change the `titled` field to `title` in the Category class, does it run as expected?

Comment: @Ben nothing changes , i think the problem is with database i tried to delete migration folder but nothing happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed ur typoes etc. please try this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Gigpost(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    categorie=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    mainphoto = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment_area(models.Model):

    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    comment=models.TextField(default='')
    commented_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

After you made any changes on your `models.py` don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

You should also check, whether the migration file was created. And maybe you need to restart your server.

Comment: thanks for your time and for your comment  , but as u noticed i did a costum user ,i'll try it now .. 
PS: i tried another project and it worked i think the problem is with database , any idea ?

Comment: it wooooooooooorked i just deleted all the migrations folder and db.sqlite3 and run migrations again, thanks for your help again

Comment: Glad you made it!